# For what values of $\alpha$ does $X_n$ converge in probability, almost surely, and rth mean

Tags: solution-verification, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be independent random variables such that $P(X_n=n^\alpha)=1/n$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ where $-\infty<\alpha<\infty$ is a constant. For what values of $\alpha$ is it true that

1. $X_n\rightarrow^p 0$?

We want $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=0$. But this is true because $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty} P(X_n=0)=1$ so it's always true, so for any $\alpha$.

3. $X_n \rightarrow ^r 0$ for a given $r>0$?

$\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty} E|X_n|^r=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} 0 * (1-1/n) + n^{\alpha r}\cdot 1/n$. So $\alpha r - 1<0$ or $\alpha < 1/r$.

I am mostly curious about 1 and 3, as I found 2 on another question on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Not sure why you think there might be a problem in it. It's just about using the definitions.